# Wordpress media upload issue could not insert attachment into the database

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

Could not insert attachment into the database.

When ever I try to upload new images from WordPress media it shows me above error.

Please help me why wp database shows this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solutins:

1. First of all check your WP database size and check whether the size is full according to your hosting provider's requirement/rule.
2. Second option, add this line into your **wp-config.php**:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

Also if you have access to **php.ini** (or php[version number].ini) file on your server, try to add this line:

```
memory_limit 512M
```

3. By default, some database configs have a collation or charset that doesn't allow special character. Check whether the file name of the image you're trying to upload is having any special characters. If so, delete them and use only alphanumeric. Then retry.
4. Also, please check your folder permission. Read more about it on https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-image-upload-issue-in-wordpress/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help it looks like a database issue having 0 as primary key in posts table

Answer (score 1):

Auto-increment missing...

Same issue. I'd migrated the site from another server. Found that the Auto-Increment flag was missing from the wp_post table's ID column. I switched that back on and the problem resolved.

It seems like ALL the tables had lost auto-increment from their ID columns though.... headache!