# Uploaded images not displaying full size preview or inserting into posts

Tags: database, uploads, media

#### Original issue

I was having an issue where image uploads gave the error “could not insert attachment into the database.”

- PHP memory limit and other settings are fine
- Disk space is fine
- Ran check on DB…no issues
- Permissions and ownership are fine

That error seems to be something to do with auto-increment getting messed up. So after trying everything else, I replicated the database and tried this on the replica:

https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/fixing-wordpress-indexes-foreign-keys-and-auto_increment-fields/

That fixed the issue but caused a new one.

#### Current issue

Now when I try to upload an image, the upload is successful, but there are strange issues.

The preview thumbnail is visible:

[image]

But if I click it, the large preview image is NOT visible.

If I copy the image URL and paste it in a browser, it works just fine.

[image]

And the image variations are all in my uploads folder and work in a browser:

[image]

If I insert the image into a post, I get this:

[image]

I still have the database from before the “fix” but I’m not sure what to do with either to resolve this.

Comment: Regarding your original install, see if the issue/solution [mentioned here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/401939/31073) might apply regarding auto increment.

Comment: Please take a backup of your site and reinstall WordPress from the WordPress update menu. If it doesn't fix it, disable your plugins and check. Announce the result.

Comment: It looks like I missed mentioning that I'd already tried changing to the default theme and disabling plugins.

I tried reinstalling Wordpress from Updates, but no change.

In fact, since I have two versions of the database (one with the original error and one with the new issue) and can switch between them, I tried it with both.